# jQuery: binding event to element directly works, binding the same on document doesn't (iOS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, pointer-events

I am currently debugging a web-app with the following element:

```
<a class="btn btn__add-to-cart" data-target="/someURL" data-cart="modal" title="add to basket">
  <svg class="icon icon__cart icon--lg" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/_ui/17.2.0.173/desktop/common/images/icons/icon-sprite.svg#cart"></use>
  </svg>
</a>
```

There is a function bound to the outer element like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-cart="modal"]', function(evt){
  alert('test-on-document');
})
```

which does *not* work on iOS 9, 10, 11 Safari and Chrome.

If I bind the same function directly to the element like this:

```
$('[data-cart="modal"]').on('click', function(evt){
  alert('test-direct');
})
```

it works - and even more magically, the first function, bound to the document, is *also* executed.

Of course, this does work in a standalone environment, but it doesn't in application context. I was looking for pointer-events in CSS or some other functions bound to it, but especially the last part (that the document-function works after adding a directly bound function) makes no sense.

Any hints?

**Solution**

After a long search, I've come up with why on iOS, the click event isn't triggered: It's simply because the "href"-attribute on the a-tag was missing. So either add "href='#"' or - look closely - add "cursor:pointer" to the a's CSS! :-o

Comment: [When you fix the typo in the first example it works fine.](https://jsfiddle.net/5e6jg3p8/2/) (`function(evt{`)

Comment: no it doesn't :) was just a typo with copy/pasting, sorry

Comment: What jQuery version you are using?

Comment: 3.2.1 - but I think that's not the point, other selectors on document work and it's also only a problem on iOS...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '[data-cart="modal"]', function(evt){
  alert('test-on-document');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn__add-to-cart" data-target="/someURL" data-cart="modal" title="add to basket">
  <svg class="icon icon__cart icon--lg" role="img" aria-hidden="true">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/_ui/17.2.0.173/desktop/common/images/icons/icon-sprite.svg#cart"></use>
  </svg>
</a>
```

This works, There is a typo in your function, evt brackets should be closed.

Comment: please read my comment & edit above, this is not the source of the problem.

Comment: May be the jQuery library, which jQuery version you are using?

Comment: @Andy I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Andy is right, I'm not sharing the whole code, because I can't. I'm looking for input on where to search.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Delegated events do not work for SVG element.

Detailed answer :
In your first example, you are attaching event handler at document level and the event bubble up from the descendant element(specified by selector) all the way up to document level and there your handler is called.
This, however, does not work when descendant is SVG.
In second example the event handler is directly on SVG element.
That's why it works.

Please see documentation for more details (Direct and delegated events
 section)
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: In 2nd example, the event handler is on the a-tag as well, not on the svg?

Comment: @RaphaelJeger I think due to the child is a svg, so it does not work. Test this, replace svg with some text and see if it works

Comment: Event does not bubble up if child is SVG. try replacing it with other HTML elements as suggested by @Huangism